# getting response code from HttpURLConnection in android

Tags: android, http, ioexception

i am establishing connection with the server and its working fine. But there are times when i try to get the response code (when server is throwing back 401, 403, 404) i am getting IO Exception. I am handling everything based on the response code. So when it throws IO exception  on

```
http.getResponseCode()
```

i am not able to read the response code. Please suggest a solution for this.

Comment: Could you post some more code?

Comment: Why can't you just catch the IOException and handle it as if you got a response code -1?

Comment: I am catching the exception. But why is it not possible to get the response code when server is throwing back 401, 403, 404. Is it the limitation that we have in HttpURLConnection class. For ex: When server is throwing 401 i.e authentication challenge, it would be very good to get the response code other than reading the exception message so that i can decide whether or not to send the request with proper user credentials.

Comment: this is the code, HttpURLConnection c = HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection(); try { c.getResponseCode() } catch(IOexception e) {}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to android 2.3 HttpUrlConnection  has few [issues](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html).  Its better to use Defaulthttpclient api. Seems your issue is similar to [this](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=592).